# CodeIgniter How to create migration new database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to create migration new database. Than I create new file migration in migrations folder 001_add_database_hasilsda.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
class Migration_Add_databases extends CI_Migration {

  public function up() {
    $this->dbforge->create_database("hasilsda");
  }

  public function down() {
    $this->dbforge->drop_database('hasilsda');
  }

}
```

Than I tried to write this code in controller/migrate.php

> ```
> $this->load->dbforge();
> if ($this->dbforge->create_database('hasilsda')) {
>   echo 'Database created!';
> }
> ```

I got error message.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to select the specified database: hasilsda
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\rumahsdaproject\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 140

I don't have idea. I need help. Thanks

Comment: It might help if you showed the code around line 140...

Comment: I have done to do this but I can't edit the file system in CI. My idea is I want to create database by creating migration but I always get error.